# SSL Certificate - Renewal vs. Requesting New

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority

Is there any benefit to renewing an existing SSL Cert as opposed to requesting a new one?

Answer (score 2):

If may.

- Renewal can be cheaper.
- If the renewal mean keeping the same private key it may impact your key management (HPKP for example)

Comment: Thanks Tom. I'm still learning about certs. Is it bad to keep the same private key?

Comment: @S.Loren except if you have a particular threat model or if you know the private key is compromised, you can keep the same private key.